# How to compare datetime.date to str in python?

Tags: python

I have a list of dates like this ['2009-12-07', '2009-12-08'] and another date like 2010-01-03. How can I compare whether 2010-01-03 is greater than the individual date inside the list?

Comment: Convert to comparable types and use `>`?

Comment: Yes, something like is 2010-01-01 > '2009-12-07'? I know i have to put them on same format but i don't know how to format.

Comment: Then *that* is something you should research. Be focused, solve it a step at a time.

Comment: You can convert the date to a string in the format "%Y-%m-%d" and compare it to other strings. Or vice versa, convert the strings to a date and do the comparison.

Answer (score 4):

To create your list of strings into a list of date objects:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_list = [datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d") for x in date_list]
```

Then just use `<` or `>` to do the comparison.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.

Answer (score 2):

Create the required objects:

```
x = ['2009-12-07', '2009-12-08']
test = datetime.date(2010,1,3)
```

Then convert and compare as needed:

```
[test > datetime.datetime.strptime(q,'%Y-%m-%d').date() for q in x]
```

Results in `[True,True]` being returned. You can break it up as you need. Error checking, etc. left to the reader.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.

Answer (score -1):

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = ['2009-12-07', '2009-12-08']
compare = datetime.strptime('2010-01-03', '%Y-%m-%d')

for date in dates:
    d = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    # or <
    # or =
    if compare > d:
        # do whatever
```